# How to send an email to each user once with the information retrieved from a query

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email to each of the users subscribed to one or more cupons. A user can have one or more cupons assigned to them. I have tried doing the following:

```
function getCronCuponDescargado(){

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();      
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = 'SELECT *
                FROM #__k2_items as k2i 
                LEFT JOIN #__cuphoneo_subscripcion as cs ON cs.item_id = k2i.id
                LEFT JOIN #__users as u ON u.id = cs.user_id
                WHERE cs.estado = 1 GROUP BY cs.item_id ORDER BY cs.user_id';

    $db->setQuery($query);  
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    $mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);  
    $emailSubject = '¡Tus Cuphones!';
    $sender = $mailer->From;
    $fcontent = '<h2>Listado de cupones</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre del cupón</th>
                            <th>Tiempo restante de cupón</th>
                        </tr>';

    foreach($result as $value){  

        $correos = array(
            $correoUser = $value->email,
            $idUser = $value->id
        ); 

        $mailer->setSender($sender);
        $mailer->addRecipient($correos);
        $mailer->setSubject($emailSubject);

        $fcontent .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$value->title.'</td>                              
                        <td>'.$value->id.'</td>
                      </tr>';

    }

    $fcontent .= '</table>';
    $mailer->setBody($fcontent);
    $send =& $mailer->Send();
}
```

`$result` returns the following:

[Result here](http://pastebin.com/9Zx8E6YL)

Right now its sending two emails to the same user which has two cupons assigned to him when it should only send one email with both cupons inside. The other user has one cupon assigned but no email is being sent to him. If you see the pastebin you will see the value of `$return` and that `Prueba de cupon 1` should be sent to one user while `Prueba de Cupon 2` and `Prueba de 4` should be sent to another.

**EDIT:** Its now sending the same email to both users with both of the users cupons in the same email.

Comment: Well you are sending a mail in every loop.

Comment: @RonniSkansing fixed it, sorry

Comment: Logically, this operation requires at least two loops, one nested in the other - the outer one to iterate the users and the inner one to iterate the current user's coupons. I only see one level of iteration, and your HTML table can only ever contain the header row and one body row...

Comment: @DaveRandom I have edited my function, I believe the only thing im missing now is the inner iteration